# How to load a component inside the parent div on material UI card click?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Started React a week ago and this might be a pretty basic question but stuck here at implementing the load of another component inside one of the divs. I am using material UI's Nav Drawer here. In the `components/NavDrawer.js` file, I want to load the ProductDetails component on the click of the card and want to render the same inside the main div of the NavDrawer.

Tried returning the desired component from the function on the click of the respective cards, but not sure how to render it on the main div. Something like `$("#id").html('something')` in jQuery.

Here is the implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactweb01-cthzf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to move to to details page right once you will click on any card ?

Comment: want to render the product details component in the same div where the cards are situated

Comment: Where above `<div className={classes.drawerHeader} />` would be fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way while using state to show details.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import ToolBar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import AccountBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountBox";
import { lightBlue } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import ImageCard from "./ImageCard";
import { fade } from "@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import { InputBase, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import ProductDetail from "./ProductDetail";
//import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const drawerWidth = 250;

var productNames = [
  "Product A",
  "Product B",
  "Product C",
  "Product D",
  "Product E"
];

const useStyle = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, #191919 60% , gray)"
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100%-${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    background: "linear-gradient(to bottom, white 80%, gray)"
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: "0 8 px",
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  },
  headerText: {
    alignContent: "center",
    background: lightBlue
  },
  cardContainer: {
    // To add the styling here
    overflow: "scroll",
    width: "100%",
    height: "30%"
  },
  search: {
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25)
    },
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    marginLeft: 50,
    width: "50%"
  },
  searchIcon: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: "inherit"
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 7),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%"
  }
}));

function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = React.useState(false);

  function handleDrawerOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleDrawerClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  function routeToPage() {
    // console.log("item clicked!");
    setShowDetails(true);
    //Need to load the component here..
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, { [classes.appBarShift]: open })}
      >
        <ToolBar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="Open Menu"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Shopify
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search.."
              classes={{ root: classes.inputRoot, input: classes.inputInput }}
            />
          </div>
        </ToolBar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Electronics", "Games", "Music", "Headphones"].map(
            (item, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={item}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item} />
              </ListItem>
            )
          )}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Account", "My Orders", "Track Orders"].map((item, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={item}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <AccountBoxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={item} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        {/* <Typography paragraph onClick={hideSideBar}>
          Welcome to the site
        </Typography> */}
        {showDetails && <ProductDetail />}
        <div>
          {productNames.map((item, index) => (
            <div onClick={routeToPage} prodName={item}>
              <ImageCard title={item} h1Text={item} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PersistentDrawerLeft;
```

Working sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactweb01-6srug

if you want to show specific product detail then instead of show hide you can have your state as:

`const [selectedProductId, setSelectedProductId] = useState(null);`

In render

`{selectedProductId && <ProductDetail id={selectedProductId} />}`

click callback

`onClick={() => routeToPage(item.id)}`

routeToPage function will be

```
function routeToPage(id) {  
  setSelectedProductId(id);   
}
```

That time it will show details when id is there(make sure id is not 0) and that id you can pass inside component to change details based on clicked product.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Will try this one